# Apache Variables to CF CGI Variables

Tags: apache, coldfusion, cgi

I have added additional Apache Variable set using SetEnv. The problem was when Iam trying to past it to CF Application and writedump(cgi) it doest have that env i set.

Apache2 Side

```
env.conf
SetEnv HELLO_WORLD "hello world"
```

CF side

```
netmon.cfm
<cfscript>
  writedump(cgi);
<cfscript>
```

Comment: Check if this article from Ben Nadel helps you - https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2838-reading-environment-variables-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: i have check that one and it doest seems to read the apache set variables

Comment: I don't think that is an easy task. Environment variables are typically passed through the different apache2 modules and then passed to cgi scripts/ssi. But that doesn't apply for cfml because that runs inside a servlet container engine (that's not a cgi script). Otherwise we wouldn't need tomcats RemoteIpValve to get protocal information on proxypass by http headers. What do you need it for? Can't you set that information with headers or by environment variables/system properties within tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is pass the environment variable into a rewrite rule or probably easier into a header variable.

```
SetEnv HELLO_WORLD "hello world"
RequestHeader set X-Custom-Message "%{HELLO_WORLD}e"
```

Then access in ColdFusion like this.

```
<cfscript>
writeDump(GetHTTPRequestData().headers['X-Custom-Message']);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Why not set it directly then with 'RequestHeader set X-Custom-Message "hello world"? The setenv, setenvif or passenv only makes sense when using these variables with conditional statements or passing the variables within/inbetween modules when running in conjuction with Tomcat.